# It might be a dumb question but want to get it clarified. Can we say 'super' as an object rather than keyword in java?

Tags: java, super

I know super is a special reserved keyword but from the way how we use it , it should be called as object. Can some one clarify whether my thought is right or wrong. Would be better if you can provide more detailed clarification on this.

Comment: Well, `this` is a reference to this object. `super` gives you a way to call methods or constructors of the parent class. `this` references this object. But there is no `super` object.

Comment: As explained below, super refers to a type, not to an object

Comment: I'm not sure what's your notion about an object, but `super` is a reference to the **immediate** superclass' object of any class in java.

Comment: No, because it has magic properties. If it was an object and you called an overridden method, it would call that method. It doesn't, it calls the overridden one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would not be correct. Super is a keyword in java used to reference the superclass of the instance of a class.
Object is an instance of a class.

You cannot use the word "super" unless an instance of a class exist, therefore, it cannot be considered equivalent to an object.

Think of a hypothetical class `Human`. You can ask me "what's your superclass" and I would say "it's `Creature`". But you cannot "create" a new `Human` by asking "what's your superclass".

Maybe your confusion comes from the usage of the word "super" in the constructor. When we make the `super();` call, we're actually executing the superclass's constructor. As you know, constructors are very particular methods and they are not invoked the same way another method would have been. If I was to refer to a getter of the superclass, I would do `super.getWhatever();` instead. However, we cannot do `super.something()` to call a constructor, so we just do `super();`.
And regarding the call to the superclass's constructor when constructing an instance of a class, that's because you cannot call me "Human" before defining me as a "Creature". So, you first create the creature characteristics on me and then you make me human.

I hope that makes sense :).